# In Galaxybase, is the first parameter of the bfsMaster method startId the id of the node?

Tags: graph-databases

Is the startId of the first parameter of the bfsMaster method in Galaxybase the same as the id of the node in the gremlin statement g.V("id")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter startId of the bfsMaster method in Galaxybase refers to the node from which the breadth-first search (BFS) will start. This startId can be any type of node ID, not necessarily an integer type. In Galaxybase, node IDs can be defined in various ways, such as string, integer, floating point, etc.

In the Gremlin statement, the "id" in g.V("id") means that you need to get the node with the ID "id". The "id" can be any type of node ID, or it can be the value of other attributes, etc.

Each node has an external id (i.e., the "external unique identifier" specified when importing, which can be interpreted as the PK of the relational database and is of type String); the nodes imported into the graph database summary will have a corresponding internal id, which is of type Long.